# insertRowsAtIndexPaths custom animations Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation

My goal is to animate every single inserted cell using the `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` function.
The only issue is the default animation style isn't exactly what I'm looking for - i need to create a custom one.
I've browsed stack for solutions and found some, but they are written in objC: [Can you do custom animations for UITableView Cell Inserts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379614/can-you-do-custom-animations-for-uitableview-cell-inserts)

I'm looking for a similar swift solution.

If anyone could share, that would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: cmon guys. before giving me a minus for a question, can you at least provide a guideline. otherwise your presence on this forum is somewhat useless.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try out the following code

`table.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(index, withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation(rawValue: 3))`

Comment: Tried it out. Nothing happened. Looks similar to reloadData, erases all animations.