# Overriding withRowAnimation styles for row insertion in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation

I'm using an `insertRowAtIndexPath` function to insert a series of rows inside my tableview.
However, the in-build animation styles `(.Fade, .Top, .Bottom e.t.c.)` do not fill my needs entirely.
I need to create my own custom animations, i know this can be done by overriding the the `UITableViewRowAnimation`, but i'm not sure how this should be handled.

Looking forward to your advices.

Appreciate any insights.

Comment: This may help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379614/can-you-do-custom-animations-for-uitableview-cell-inserts

Comment: @johnykumar thank you. yes, i've seen it. the issue is - its written in ObjC and i can't replicate the solution, unfortunately.

Comment: ok let me try in swift will reply you soon.

Comment: @johnykumar any success?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This in your UITableView subclass.

```
override func insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths: [NSIndexPath], withRowAnimation animation: UITableViewRowAnimation) {
    super.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)

    self.endUpdates()
    self.beginUpdates()

    for indexPath:NSIndexPath in indexPaths {

        let cell:UITableViewCell? = (super.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath))

        if cell != nil {
            var frame:CGRect = (cell?.frame)!
            frame.origin.x = (cell?.frame.size.width)!
            cell?.frame = frame
            frame.origin.x = 0

            let animationBlock = { () -> Void in
                cell!.frame = frame;
            }

            if UIView.respondsToSelector(Selector("animateWithDuration(duration: , delay: , usingSpringWithDamping dampingRatio: , initialSpringVelocity velocity: , options: , animations: , completion: ")) {
                // UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options:0.0, animations: animationBlock, completion:nil)
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: animationBlock, completion: nil)
            } else {
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.0, options:UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: animationBlock, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the `endUpdates()` and `beginUpdates()`?

Comment: @NRitH its just swift converted code of link which i suggest to follow.i only converted it to swift.

Comment: thank you for the great effort. although, i've got an issue while implementing the code. i don't have an `UITableView` class, I'm just using the `UITableViewDatasource` and the `UITableViewDelegate` as well as `UIViewController` for basic table functions - when i try to add an `UITableView` class or replace the current `UIViewController` i get a crash.

Comment: Create a class while creating choose subclass of UITableVIew and after that add this method in .m file then go to your storyboard or xib then select tableview and go in Identity Inspector and assign your class for tableview.

Comment: i've been able to make it work with a few tweaks - [NSIndexPath] should be changed to [AnyObject] e.t.c. in the code. Yet the issue is - it animates the insertion of a whole block, i was looking for the insertion of every single cell. Would that be possible?

Comment: Besides this animation only allows me to control the duration (its ease out from left all the time) and applies only for visible rows.

Comment: you can pass one indexpath for single row in it with single object in array and for duration 0.3 is given change value according to your need.

Comment: sounds reasonable, but i'm not sure how to do it. currently i have multiple objects in the array.

Comment: create a temp array in for loop for iterating your objects and add single object in temp array call insert method in for loop then delete object from temp array with the for loop.

Comment: that would be a good idea if i had a blank slate uitableview, but all my cell insertion logic is tied up to the array of arrays. this would require reworking the project entirely. need to find a different solution (

Comment: dont do like that it will effect your whole project whereever you use that array.do same as i have wrote above.

Comment: how about we track the specific indexPath range of the inserted cells and use it instead of AnyObject? then we can either use a for loop from your code or chain animation actions for every single row one after another. that might work.

Comment: it depends on the user action or your projects functionality where you want to insert cell you will get index path.

Comment: thank you for great help. so far i haven't been able to find a better solution of overriding the insertRowsAtIndexPaths function. yet still struggling with
-1) Inserting every row separately with animation
-2) Keeping the animation from dissapearing when the cells are hidden from view (during scroll)

Comment: there is another method willDisplaycell whenever a row is shown on the screen you can add same functionality of animation in this.it will show for every cell.

Comment: the issue with willDisplaycell is that it always reloads a cell with animation, each time you scroll. i need it just once.